# How can I make images use the optimal amount of space without flexboxes

Tags: css

In a sequence of images like the code at the bottom (with inconsistent image sizes), the next row of image starts at the bottom of the tallest image. I know this can be remedied with flex-boxes like in this tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_grid_responsive.asp, however, I need the images to scale like in the following code.

```css
.holder {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  width: 500px;
}

.holder>img {
  width:32%;
  transition: 100ms;
}

.holder>img:hover {
  width:66%
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/403571/pexels-photo-403571.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/219779/pexels-photo-219779.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/6936/desk-office-plant-succulent-6936.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/8795/plant-cactus.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/56589/cactus-plant-plant-rack-green-56589.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/137036/pexels-photo-137036.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940">
</div>
```

Is it possible to have masonry type images that can scale?